# How to update TensorFlow.js saved / trained model

Tags: node.js, machine-learning, keras, model, tensorflow.js

Hi I would like to know how to update the TensorFlow js saved model in node js,

I created a basic neural network in TensorFlow js using NodeJS  and saved the trained model and it produced model.json and weights.bin file.

I've seen that we can update the trained model in keras in Python.

But there is no example for updating the model in TensorFlow js, NodeJS and JS.

Please someone help to update the trained model.

## model load and update code

```
var tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
async funtion load(){
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(url);
}
load().then(() => {
    model.predict(tf.tensor1d([5]))
    model.predict(tf.tensor1d([5]), tf.tensor1d([15]));
    model.predict(tf.tensor1d([5]))
})
```

Answer (score 3):

A saved model can be loaded back and used for further training.

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(url);
model.predict(feature) // predict with old model
await model.fit(features, labels); // this will update the weights of the model
model.predict(feature) // predict with new model
```

The retrained model can be saved back and this will update its weights. It is as if the model was trained on both the initial data and the current data which means that it can predict data coming from both sources.

However, if the new data differ significantly from the initial data, the model will be unable to predict well from the initial data again. This issue is discussed well [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352750/is-there-a-way-to-incorporate-new-data-into-an-already-trained-neural-network-wi/352771#352771)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I have tried this way by loading trained model and do model l.predict(new_feature, new_label). But it still gives me old value when I predict, it is not looking as updating the model

Comment: `loadLayersModel` is asynchrone so it needs to be `await`ed. I edited my code

Comment: Yeah I already loaded the layer with async/await method , but it is not updating the loaded model, it just overlapping.

Comment: what do you mean by `overlapping` ? Could you please add the code to your question ?

Comment: This is my code, the tensor (x:5) had tensor (y:10) , when i train the model.
even i put new value( x:5, y: 15 ) in the above code by loading model, it still returns 10 as y label

Comment: Actually you need to use `fit` to update the model weights. See the edited answer

Comment: I tried with it, and it is not updating the model it just override the old nodes with new node that we give in fit function after loaded the model

Comment: What do you mean by updating then ?

Comment: Updating the models in the sense, if I trained the model with 10 data initially and saved it. If I have 10 more data later I have to update it to the model instead of retraining the whole model again with the old 10+ new 10 data

Comment: If the nodes are updated as you said then the model is updated. I don't know what difference you are making between the two. Granted you need to train the model longer maybe for the new value to be reflected in the prediction.

Comment: Normally the code do just that. However, if your new data differ significantly from your initial data, the model will not be able to remember the initial data